# How to send properly currency symbol inside json to web client ?

Tags: java, json, client-server

I'm sending symbols as : €, ₤, but the problem is that the client sees it corrupted.
Should I send him the unicode (e.g., \u20AC) so it will render it properly ? 
Currently I'm sending the symbol as Java String.

Comment: Unicode escape sequence is always safe. But check your web service's encoding. If it's not UTF-8, it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside JSON to a web client... sounds like an API response? Then it should be html-encoded imho:

```
&euro;
&#163;
```

will give € and £

Always use charset UTF-8, except if you have a good reason to use another (legacy systems)